# SQL Server Import CSV Data into Temp Table Unable to Query Imported Data

Tags: csv, import, ssms

I have imported CSV Data into a temporary table named #CSVImportTable using the SSMS Import Wizard.  After doing so however I'm not able to query the temp table.  My assumption is I am needing to gain access to the 'Connection' that is tied to the temp table however this is just a guess.

How do I query the data from this temp table after having used the wizard?  I can see the temp table when viewing System Databases --> tempdb --> Temporary Tables --> dbo.#CSVImportTable but I don't know how to connect or access the instance for which the temp table was created in order to query it from within SSMS.

How do I overcome this?

**Screenshot of Visible Temp Table Created using the Import Wizard**

[image: CSVImportTable]

**Screenshot of the Wizard Results before clicking Finish**

[image: SSMSImportWizard]

I am using [SSMS v18.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15).  There were no Stack Overflow tags for this version however I have added a hyperlink to Microsoft's download page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my issue was to simply INSERT my data into a Global Temp Table and then on the SSMS Tabs for which I want to use that data I just SELECT the data out of the Global Temp Table into a Local Temp Table.  So I've resorted to pasting in at the top of all my scripts for which I need to work with this data the SQL to just move the data into a Temp Table.

```
/* Grab data out of Global Temp Table and store it in Local Temp Table to use for the Life of the Session */
SELECT *
INTO #CSVImportTable
FROM ##CSVDataImport
```